# Grab id from a select option field and update it in the selected user

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having some problems while creating my program. I have a select field which shows all the users from the table users and I want that when I select a user and press link I want that it updates the users userid into puserid from the table properties

The php code:

```
//connect with the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("ocm2inf_ocm",$con);
$get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE PortalId = '14'");
$option = '';

//create rows of the users
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['UserId'].'">'.$row['firstName']. str_repeat('&nbsp;', 1). $row['UserId'].'</option>';
}

//update the row in the database after pressing the button
if(isset($_POST['linkownersandproperties']))
{
  $UserId = $_POST['UserIdOwner'];

  $sql = "UPDATE properties SET puserId='$UserId' WHERE propertyId=$id";
}
```

The html code:

```
<form class="create section" action="" method="post">
  <select class="form-control" name="UserIdOwner">
    <?php echo $option; ?>
  </select>
  <br />
  <button style="width:110px; margin-left:10px;" type="submit" name="linkownersandproperties" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-button1" required="required">Link</button>
  </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

Comment: Use mysqli_prepare as well. Never use raw $_POST data. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php. Also, I am not sure where the $id in propertyId is coming from?

Comment: Thats the id from the property wich is created somewhere else in the file but that variable works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this rule
`$sql = "UPDATE properties SET puserId='$UserId' WHERE propertyId=$id";`

To this rule

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE properties SET puserId='$UserId' WHERE propertyId='$id'");
```

Put this under `$sql` in the if statement

```
$query = mysql_query($sql, $db);
if (!$sql) {
    echo "Failed";
} else {
    echo "Executed";
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\Urbytus project\edit-properties.php on line 304

Comment: @NielsNouwens put it under the `$sql` variable in the if

Comment: UPDATE properties SET puserId='116950' WHERE propertyId=82332

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\Urbytus project\edit-properties.php on line 302
Executed

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\Urbytus project\edit-properties.php on line 302
Executed